How to pass a parameter to an import
I have a Python import that is a wrapper for a legacy Windows DLL; the import declares a number of interface functions/wrappers for functions in the DLL (mostly to handle data type differences).
I'd like to be able to externally control which DLL the import loads; something like this:
        if environment == 'release':
            mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('../DLL/x64/Release/scanner64.dll')
        elif environment == 'debug':
            mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('../DLL/x64/Debug/scanner64.dll')
        elif environment == 'local':
            mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./Scanner64.dll')
        else:
            print("Valid environments are release, debug, and local")
            exit()
   


I've tried declaring 'environment' as global in my main Python script, but that doesn't work.  I also tried putting the majority of the contents of the import in an init() funciton, but that doesn't work either (as the scope of the function defs is within the init function--not visible to the importing script.

With all your logic in functions, you can delay loading until it's needed
# library

mydll = None

def load(environment="local"):
    global mydll
    if environment == 'release':
        mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('../DLL/x64/Release/scanner64.dll')
    elif environment == 'debug':
        mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('../DLL/x64/Debug/scanner64.dll')
    elif environment == 'local':
        mydll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./Scanner64.dll')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Valid environments are release, debug, and local")

# rest of the logic

Now when importing your function, you just need to load it
import mylibrary
mylibrary.load(environment)

You might also consider automatic loading from an env var
# again in your library
try:
    loader_environment = os.environ["SOME_ENV_LOADER_VALUE"]
except KeyError:  # env var not set
    pass
else:
    load(loader_environment)  # consider another try:except for better error
    #logger.debug(f"using SOME_ENV_LOADER_VALUE as {loader_environment} from env")

and additionally gating against re-loading
def load(...):
    global mydll
    if mydll is not None:
        raise RuntimeError("already loaded: do not reload")
        # logger.error(f"attempted to reload with env: {environment}")


I think using an environment variable may be my only option; I should have included the next few lines from the import, as I'm delaring functions from the DLL:
setFlags = mydll.setFlags
enableFlag = mydll.enableFlag

These won't work unless the DLL has been loaded.

maybe! still, perhaps you pack those into your loader function too

tried that; but then their scope is within the loader function and not visible outside it (to the importing script).  i could try making them global and see if that works ;)

indeed - though if you find you have a great many globals, making a dict to hold 'em all or some custom class which wraps it further may be useful, or a mix of both (please plus good docs)
